# How to generate recurring event objects using recurrence rule (RRule.js)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, icalendar, rrule

I've got a complex problem I'm trying to solve.

I'm building a calendar application that allows users to save recurring events in to the database. To handle the recurring events, I'm using the [RRule.js](https://github.com/jkbrzt/rrule) library to create a recurrence rule that generates the dates the event needs to recur on.

I'm now trying to work out how to display this information in my Calendar. Do I:

1. Iterate over the Cursor on the server side, and for each event create a new object for each of the recurring events?
2. Publish the events and then on the client side iterate over the array of event objects and push a new event object for each recurring event?

How do I go about doing either of them?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: This is somewhat subjective as there might be good reasons to do it either way. Personally I'd publish the base objects then create the recurring objects in a *local* (non-managed) collection on the client. The question is then what do you do if an instance of a recurring event is modified?

Comment: I guess you could always have an "exceptions" list.

Comment: @MichelFloyd thanks for the answer. I have an idea of how to handle exceptions, but I'm not sure how to handle creating the recurring objects in a local (non-managed) collection. Would you be able to show me an example of how to do that?
Thanks for your help

Comment: [This article](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/using-meteor-local-collections-to-support-browser-based-cryptography) might be of help.

Comment: @MichelFloyd That article was super helpful! I'm now publishing the events to the client and then using a new local collection to loop over each event and 'expand' it by inserting a new document for each recurrence. This is exactly what I was looking for! One thing I'm aware of is that the local collection holds all of the documents in it. Should I just remove them all each time a component that relies on that collection unmounts? Thanks a huge amount for your help!

Comment: Depends on how many events you have and how concerned you are with memory consumption. If you have hundreds it's probably not a big deal. Hundreds of thousands? Then yes by all means.